# Group/Cluster K-Fold CV with Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I need to do a K-fold CV on some models, but I need to ensure the validation (test) data set is clustered together by a group and `t` number of years. `GroupKFold` is close, but it still splits up the validation set (see second fold).

For example, if I have a set of data with years from 2000-2008 and I want to K-fold into 3 groups. The appropriate sets would be: Validation: 2000-2002, Train: 2003-2008; V:2003-2005, T:2000-2002 & 2006-2008; and V: 2006-2008, T: 2000-2005).

Is there a way to group and cluster the data using K-Fold CV where the validation set is clustered by `t` years?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

X = [0.1, 0.2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.3, 4.55, 5.8, 8.8, 9, 10, 0.1, 0.2, 2.2]
y = ["a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "b", "b"]
groups = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
for train_index, test_index in gkf.split(X, y, groups=groups):
    print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index)
```

Output:

```
Train: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5 10 11 12] Validation: [6 7 8 9]
Train: [3 4 5 6 7 8 9] Validation: [ 0  1  2 10 11 12]
Train: [ 0  1  2  6  7  8  9 10 11 12] Validation: [3 4 5]
```

Desired Output (assume 2 years for each group):

```
Train: [ 7 8 9 10 11 12 ] Validation: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
Train: [0 1 2 10 11 12 ] Validation: [ 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
Train: [ 0  1  2  3 4 5 ] Validation: [6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
```

Although, the test and train subsets are not sequential along and can select more years to group.

Comment: I don't see how your `groups` list is related to your desired output or how your desired output is linked to the 9 years from 2000 to 2008 you mentioned before. Maybe its me, but I don't quite understand how input and output are related and what your goal is.

Comment: @Merlin1896 In the desired output, I am selecting group 1 & 2, 2 & 3, and 3 &4 for validation. I then want to train using the remaining, so group 3 & 4, 1 & 4, and 1 & 2. In your answer, you are only selecting one group as the validation set where I want two (or more in larger data sets). You've got the right idea, I just want to select groups that are clustered, such as two years.

Comment: But why is index 6 three times in the test set and never in the training set? I assume this is a typo? If so, please check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly.

The [LeaveOneGroupOut](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html#sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut) method from scikits `model_selection` might help:

Lets say you assign the group label 0 to all the data points from 2000-2002, label 1 for all data points between 2003 and 2005 and label 2 for the data in 2006-2008.
Then you could use the following method, to create training and test splits, where the three test splits are created from one of the three groups:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut
import numpy as np
groups=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
X=np.random.random(len(groups))
y=np.random.randint(0,4,len(groups))

logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
print("n_splits=", logo.get_n_splits(X,y,groups))
for train_index, test_index in logo.split(X, y, groups):
    print("train_idx:", train_index, "test_idx:", test_index)
```

Output:

```
n_splits= 3
train_idx: [ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17] test_idx: [0 1 2 3]
train_idx: [ 0  1  2  3 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17] test_idx: [4 5 6 7 8 9]
train_idx: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] test_idx: [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
```

---

### Edit

I think I now finally understood what you want. Sorry that it took me so long.

I dont think that your desired split method is already implemented in sklearn. But we can easily extend the BaseCrossValidator method.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import BaseCrossValidator
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array

class GroupOfGroups(BaseCrossValidator):
    def __init__(self, group_of_groups):
        """
        :param group_of_groups: list with length n_splits. Each entry in the list is a list with group ids from
 set(groups). In each of the n_splits splits, the groups given in the current group_of_groups sublist are used 
for validation.
        """
        self.group_of_groups = group_of_groups

    def get_n_splits(self, X=None, y=None, groups=None):
        return len(self.group_of_groups)

    def _iter_test_masks(self, X=None, y=None, groups=None):
        if groups is None:
            raise ValueError("The 'groups' parameter should not be None.")
        groups=check_array(groups, copy=True, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
        for g in self.group_of_groups:
            test_index = np.zeros(len(groups), dtype=np.bool)
            for g_id in g:
                test_index[groups == g_id] = True
            yield test_index
```

The usage is quite simple. As before, we define `X,y` and `groups`. Additionally we define a list of lists (groups of groups) which define which groups should be used together in which test fold.
So `g_of_g=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]` means that groups 1 and 2 are used as test set in the first fold, while the remaining groups 3 and 4 are used for training. In fold 2, data from groups 2 and 3 are used as test set etc.

I am not quite happy with the naming "GroupOfGroups" so maybe you find something better.

Now we can test this cross validator:

```
X = [0.1, 0.2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.3, 4.55, 5.8, 8.8, 9, 10, 0.1, 0.2, 2.2]
y = ["a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "b", "b"]
groups = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
g_of_g = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
gg = GroupOfGroups(g_of_g)
print("n_splits=", gg.get_n_splits(X,y,groups))
for train_index, test_index in gg.split(X, y, groups):
    print("train_idx:", train_index, "test_idx:", test_index)
```

Output:

```
n_splits= 3
train_idx: [ 6  7  8  9 10 11 12] test_idx: [0 1 2 3 4 5]
train_idx: [ 0  1  2 10 11 12] test_idx: [3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
train_idx: [0 1 2 3 4 5] test_idx: [ 6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
```

Please keep in mind that I did not include a lot of checks and didn't do thorough testing. So verify carefully that this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! This is close, but I need more than one group clustered, such as 1 &2 or 2 & 3. Another alternative would be TimeSeriesSplit, but that is essentially would you are proposing.

Comment: 1 & 2 are clustered together in the second training set, 2&3 are clustered together in the first training set. So when do you need 1&2 clustered together in the validation set? Could you provide the desired output of your initial example?

Comment: The test_idx only includes one group where I need two (or more) groups. I've updated my question with the desired output; although, the CV does not need to be sequential.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!